# Counting down days not showing the right number of days

Tags: php, date

I need help.. Is this right?

Start Date: Mar 16, 2014

End Date: Mar 19, 2014

Results: 2 Days

```
$plantEnd = get_the_author_meta('plantEnd', $sellerID );
$plantStart = get_the_author_meta('plantStart', $sellerID );

$future = $plantEnd;

$d = new DateTime($future);
echo $d->diff(new DateTime())->format('%a').' Days';
```

Why does it says 2 days? Isn't it 3 days? Im confused..

Comment: it says 2 days because there are 2 days between the 16th and 19th...(17,18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't actually using `$plantStart` in your code and instead using the current time, you're basically getting a difference between now (the time the script was run, on server's time zone) and the start of Mar 19, 2014 (0h:0m:0s). So what you are *really* getting is something like 2 days 5 hours 3 minutes 25 seconds (depending on when you run it vs. server time.

for example, when I run this locally:

`$d->diff(new DateTime())->format('%d:%H:%i:%s');`

I get `2:04:59:25`

So there's more to it than just getting that "2" returned.. you're just not formatting for it.

And again, you aren't actually using the `$plantStart` anywhere either. So if you were to do this:

```
<?php
$plantEnd = '2014-03-19';//get_the_author_meta('plantEnd', $sellerID );
$plantStart = '2014-03-16'; //get_the_author_meta('plantStart', $sellerID );

$future = $plantEnd;

$d = new DateTime($future);
echo $d->diff(new DateTime($plantStart))->format('%d:%H:%i:%s');
?>
```

You will see it outputs `3:00:0:0` (or you could continue to just use `%d` and get the "3"). This is because `$plantStart` (presumably - based on your post) just specifies `yyyy-mm-dd`, so passing just the `yyyy-mm-dd` value will put the `hh:mm:ss` at `0:0:0` (beginning of day) , so it will be a full day's calculation, which has the effect of "rounding up" to the whole day increment.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that it's actually 2 days, someodd hours, and someodd minutes, or something to that effect. Because you're formatting to just do days, you're losing the nuances. I'd change the code to say "2.4 days" (and for the life of me I can't remember how I did this in the past...)

EDIT: in the past I have simply used date() instead of DateTime().

I did a little research, and you might want `format('%d')." Days";`

Comment: well, 2 days + whatever time diff between (now) and midnight server-time. Same principle though

Comment: Thanks, Crayon Violent... that is a good distinction, between now and midnight server-time. Either way, it's being rounded to 2 days, and chopping off the remainder.