# 3 days is only 2 days and 11 hours away?

Tags: php, date, time

This is a follow up to this question: [Counting down days not showing the right number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444662/counting-down-days-not-showing-the-right-number-of-days)

I'm still confused about dates and times.

Setting the start and end times:

```
// start date: set the time of when you click the link
$startTime = strtotime('now');
$plantStart = date('M d, Y h:i:s', $startTime);

// end date: 3 days from the time of when you click the link 
$date = strtotime("+3 day", $startTime);
$plantEnd = date('M d, Y h:i:s', $date);
```

This gives me:

Mar 17, 2014 07:33:45 (start)

Mar 20, 2014 07:33:45 (end)

Now, the problem.. when I do this:

```
// show how many days/hours till $plantEnd date

$d = new DateTime($plantEnd);
$daysHours = $d->diff(new DateTime())->format('%d Days, %H Hours');
echo $daysHours;
```

The result is always something like: 2 Days, 11 Hours its never 3 days 0 hours or 2 days 23 hours.. Is it still just getting the time till 0:00:00 on the 3rd day instead of to the exact minute of the time?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Also, you're mixing `strtotime()` + `date()` and DateTime. **Use only one.** What exactly are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: Replace `new DateTime()` by `new Datetime($plantStart)`. What is the result?

Comment: Instead of dinking around with both strtotime and DateTime, and converting back and forth between strings, timestamps, and dates how about you *only* use DateTime? I'll wager that there are some timezone issues at play here.

Comment: (Besides that it's a bad habbit to switch back and forward between date-notations.) In `$plantStart = date('M d, Y h:i:s', $startTime);` the small `h` represents the hour in 12-hour-notation (AM/PM), switch to capital `H` (24-hour-notation) to solve the issue with 2 Days, 11 Hours. 2 days, 23 hours is due to rounding.

Answer (score 1):

As Yohann Tilotti mention in the comments, the issue it that `new DateTime()` is never initialized in the `diff()` function.

What you probably meant was: `$d->diff(new DateTime($plantStart))`.

You can see a running example here: http://ideone.com/FU8akb

Answer (score 0):

Like I commented, stick to one method of dates. The preferred method being `DateTime`:

```
$plantStart = new DateTime('now');
echo $plantStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Output: 2014-03-17 12:56:00
$plantEnd = new DateTime('now + 3 days');
echo $plantEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Output: 2014-03-20 12:56:00
$daysHours = $plantEnd->diff(new DateTime())->format('%d Days, %H Hours');
echo $daysHours;
// Output: 3 Days, 00 Hours
```

Comment: Replace `$plantEnd->diff(new DateTime())` by `$plantEnd->diff($plantStart)`. It's not necessary to create 3 objects!